# Select combobox in MVC .net core linked to a ID

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-3.1

I trying to learm MVC .net core and I need to populate a combobox and save in to Database the ID of combobox.

I have this code in my controller:

```
ViewBag.Categories = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem{ Text="history", Value="1"},
                new SelectListItem{ Text="literature", Value="2"},
            };
```

here the code in my view:

```
 <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <label asp-for="IdCategory">Category</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6">
            <select asp-for="IdCategory" name="CategoryId" asp-items="ViewBag.Categories">
                <option>-- select the category --</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="IdCategory" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The combobox show correctly the content but after I save in to the database the field "IdCategory" = 0.

My impression is that the view try to save "history" in field "IdCategory" and not "1" that is the ID.

If this is true, how I can force to save the ID and not the text ?

Thanks

Update here the controller:

```
public IActionResult Upsert(int? id)
{

    ViewBag.Categories = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem{ Text="history", Value="1"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text="literature", Value="2"},
    };


    Book = new Book();
    if (id == null)
    {
        //create
        return View(Book);
    }
    //update
    Book = _db.Books.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
    if (Book == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(Book);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Upsert()
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Book.Id == 0)
        {
            //create
            _db.Books.Add(Book);
        }
        else
        {
            _db.Books.Update(Book);
        }
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(Book);
}
```

here the complete view:

```
@model BookListMVC.Models.Book

<br />
<h2 class="text-info">@(Model.Id!=0 ? "Edit" : "Create") Book</h2>
<br />

<div class="border container" style="padding:30px;">
    <form method="post">
        @if (Model.Id != 0)
        {
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />}
        <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="Name"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="Author"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="Author" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Author" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="ISBN"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="ISBN" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ISBN" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="ISBN"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="ISBN" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ISBN" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="IdCategory">Category</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <select asp-for="IdCategory" name="CategoryId" asp-items="@ViewBag.Categories">
                    <option>-- select the category --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="IdCategory" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3 offset-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">
                    @(Model.Id != 0 ? "Update" : "Create")
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success form-control">Back to List</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

and the book class:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public int IdCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ASP.NET is a web app framework, not a data access library. What you posted doesn't show any attempt to save data to a database, or even *read* data from a database

Comment: Please show the whole view and controller for this view.

Comment: Can you share the code which saves the value to the database?

Comment: You have right, I have updated the question.

Comment: Are you able to show your book class

Comment: Just looking over your post controller method. You don't appear to be sending an object back to the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the post to this. You're not getting the posted details from the page

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Upsert(BookListMVC.Models.Book model)
{

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if (model.Id == 0)
    {
        //create
        _db.Books.Add(model);
    }
    else
    {
        _db.Books.Update(model);
    }
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Just a note. Many will also recommend that you don't use database classes between your views and controllers.

Comment: This allow me to save the Id of comboxbox in the field: "IdCategory" at the place of description ? How ? Can you explain better ?

Comment: In this test project all work perfectly. The problem is only how I can save the ID index of combobox in the field "IdCategory". I think actually the combobox pass the text and not the ID. This is my problem.

Comment: Not sure how the values are coming across but if they are, great. Your problem is you've got the wrong name on your select element. should be IdCategory not CategoryId

Comment: Just so you know. It's the name attribute that is used for binding. If you're ever unsure you can use the htmlhelper to generate name and Id. Something like....... <select id="@Html.IdFor(m=> m.IdCategory)" name="@Html.NameFor(m=>m.IdCategory)"> Instead of writing it manually. It may not be the modern way though.

Comment: Thank you. Only to understand with this code, How Combobox  understand that must use the ID and not the description ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226878/discussion-between-rob-white-and-user3449922).